# CakePHP/PHP print extra unknown symbol

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple function, it prints out either 1 or 0.
And in the CakePHP template, it directly puts out the result.

I discovered i get extra "??" when I was testing my PHP<->JS json communications, JS never parses my result. And I figured this way to test it.

When I copy (select all) the result into Notepad++, I found there were 2 questions marks in front of my result ("??result") instead of "result". My Notepad++ default new file was in ANSI, and I lost the 2 questions marks after I change the encondings to "UTF-8"

All of these started to happening all of a sudden. I was ok on a previous finished page, and getting these errors after I started a new one. I dunno what happened.

Enviroment:

Notepad++

WAMP 2.5

CakePHP 2.5

EDIT:
after some research, the problem could be something with BOM. I am not quite sure with it. I resaved files to UTF-8 without BOM. It did not seem helpful.

I started to notice this error when my js could not parse the JSON returned from php. and I copied them to some JSON checker sites. when i did it, there were several unknown charaters('?',etc depending on the site i was using) in the front. And then I did some simple tests and traced the problem to php end.

Comment: When there are no ?? in the content, copy all codes in Notepad++, change to file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM, paste the contents and save the file.

Comment: @Raptor the file encodings are in UTF-8, i get the ?? when I copy the web content (it is 1). it only gets me ?? if copy it into Notepad++ in ANSI.

Comment: @Raptor, the web content is 1 (appears to be 1). the hidden ?? appears in ANSI

Comment: @Raptor, if i type 1 in a utf-8 file and convert it ANSI, its still 1,no ??. this is really confusing me

Comment: There's no point to convert a UTF-8 file to ANSI, which has high chance of losing precision on contents.

Comment: @Raptor ,the point is, i started to unable decoding my JSON printed by  php in js. And then I did the test and found the ??. I get unexpected token all of a sudden. i was working like 10mins ago, and it stopped working when go back it after, which i did not modify anything.

Comment: @Raptor, when i first got the "unexpected token" error. I copied my JSON (generated by php) to some json checker sites. And when i do, i have several unknown symbols in the front (which i did not intend to )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, It's the evil BOM.. problem solved. God, it is so hard to be dealing with other languages which requires more than ASCII.